# Incrementing a string which contains an integer gets an error

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel

I have a string which includes a integer at the end of it . For example.

> $data = "TN01Y00099";

What I want to do is to get the integers from the string and then increase it once and save it back to that string .
For example , I want to increase the previous string as ,

> $data = "TN01Y00100";

I tried the following code for that .

```
$data['kitNo'] = "TN01Y00099";
$KitNoInt = substr($data['kitNo'], 5);
$KitNoInt = (int)$KitNoInt;
$originalKitNo = $KitNoInt;
$kitno = ++$KitNoInt;
$kit1 = str_replace($originalKitNo, $kitno, $data['kitNo']);
```

But it adds the integer into like this .

> $kit1 = TN01Y000100

Can somebody help me to riddle this .

Comment: Does the string have a fixed lenght?

Comment: What if number exceeds 99999

Comment: @dparoli not fixed

Comment: You are replacing `99` with `100` here, of course you get an extra digit this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to add 1 to the number, then PHP allows you to [increment the original string](https://www.php.net/language.operators.increment) and will adjust it for you...

```
$data = "TN01Y00099";
$data++;
echo $data;
```

gives...

```
TN01Y00100
```

Comment: wow! never knew that. Also it keeps the variable as type string.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. I have wasted my 1 hour researching on this . But you simply solved my problem within a minute.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
$data['kitNo'] = "TN01Y00099";
    $KitNoInt = substr($data['kitNo'], 5);
    $KitNoInt = (int)$KitNoInt;
    $originalKitNo = str_pad($KitNoInt, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $kitno = $KitNoInt + 1 ;
    $temp  = str_pad($kitno, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $kit1 = str_replace($originalKitNo, $temp, $data['kitNo']);
    return $kit1;
```

Comment: I found another simple solution which is answered by @nigel .Anyway, thanks for the effort .